# Position of an imageview changing when searching for an item in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a `RecyclerView` in which I have an `ImageView` for each item in the form of `sendEmail` icon. Initially, the `ImageView` is visible but once I click on it, I hide it using `setVisibility(View.GONE)` and update the `Adapter`.

Now, when I click on the `sendEmail` icon, I hide the icon in that position instantly using `reportitems.get(position).setStatus("emailsent");`. Now, if, before the `search` operation, the second item had the `ImageView` visible and first item did not, then after search if the second item were to be the only item that is relevant, then the `ImageView` does not show up there in the first position. I am using dynamic search where upon inputting a character, the adapter refreshes instantly and shows the updated RecyclerView. How can I fix this issue?

[image: I have added the image of my recyclerview below]

**After search, even though SQ 322 should have the `sendEmail` icon, it does not show up**

[image]

**Activity code**

```
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ReportAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onSendEmailClick(int position){


        flightNumber=reportitems.get(position).getFlightNumber();
        departureDate=reportitems.get(position).getDepartureDate();

        FlightClosureStatus flightClosureStatus=new FlightClosureStatus(flightNumber,departureDate,"emailsent");
        flightViewModel.updateFlightClosureStatus(flightClosureStatus);

        reportitems.get(position).setStatus("emailsent");
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        }
```

**Adapter Code**

```
public class ReportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportAdapter.ReportViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ReportItem> reportlist;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private Context mContext;

    public ReportAdapter(ArrayList<ReportItem> reportlist, Context context) {
        this.reportlist = reportlist;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onSendEmailClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ReportViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView departureDate;
        public TextView flightNumber;
        public ImageView emailView;
  
        public ReportViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener, Context context) {
            super(itemView);
            departureDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.departureDaterecyclerview);
            flightNumber =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.flightnumberrecyclerview);
            emailView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sendemailIcon);
           
            emailView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onSendEmailClick(position);

                        }
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReportViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.report_listing_item, parent, false);
        ReportViewHolder rvh= new ReportViewHolder(v,mListener,mContext);
        return rvh;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ReportItem currentItem = reportlist.get(position);

        //here i am setting the visibility of the imageview to gone
        if(currentItem.getStatus().contentEquals("emailsent")){
            holder.emailView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        holder.flightNumber.setText(currentItem.getFlightNumber());
        holder.departureDate.setText((currentItem.getDepartureDate()));


    }

    public List<ReportItem> getList() {
        return reportlist;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I search for an item in the RecyclerView, the position of the ImageView changes upon search ` That can never happen with a search. Only if you change the items in the adapter. Please reformulate.

Comment: @blackapps reformulated

Comment: `when I search for an item in the RecyclerView, I observe that the ImageView for respective items is rearranged ` Well that is impossible. I said that before. A search will not change anything. Only if you filter your data list in the adapter. Please reformulate.

Comment: If you rotatate your device, then is the same icon invisible?

Comment: @blackapps I reformulated again. And I am testing on emulator, and am not rotating the device

Comment: You can rotate the emulator too so you can answer my question.

Comment: Your reformulating brings nothing. Still the same error.

Comment: @blackapps I tried rotating with Fn + CTRL + F12 but it does not work

Comment: @blackapps On rotating the same icon is invisible after search for SQ 322. Before I search, it is visible as in the first screenshot

Comment: @blackapps I removed the first sentence which was causing confusion

Comment: The confusion is still there as a search operation would change nothing.

Comment: Then what could be altering the position of the sendmail icon? Could it be this line `reportitems.get(position).setStatus("emailsent");`?

Comment: I am only able to point this bug when I search, but yes I do agree with you that a simple search would not change anything. Hence I am asking for help to gauge where I am going wrong

Comment: Well then what are you doing instead? Reformulate.

Comment: `private ArrayList<ReportItem> reportlist;` Say the list originally contains 100 items. Now you are doing something and the list suddenly contains 25 items. Or one item.  Then what have you done? I would not call that searching.

Comment: @blackapps yup, I got your point, it makes complete sense. Hence I again reformulated the question, to explain my problem. Thanks for pointing it out and explaining. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `onBindViewHolder` with below, basically recycler uses items from pool when available, and once the item visibility is `GONE` and it is never set to `VISIBLE` again unless you do it

```
 @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ReportItem currentItem = reportlist.get(position);

        //here i am setting the visibility of the imageview to gone
        if(currentItem.getStatus().contentEquals("emailsent")){
            holder.emailView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            holder.emailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.flightNumber.setText(currentItem.getFlightNumber());
        holder.departureDate.setText((currentItem.getDepartureDate()));


    }
```